# How to remove extra space on website right side?

Tags: html, css

I am very new at coding and have some struggle finding what I did that makes this website not responsive, testing it on devtools and it leaves empty space to the right side of the page and I just can't find a fix for it. I tried to see if it was some of my images size that was the issue but still didn't find a solution. Any advice on what I could do would be much apriciated!
I leave my code for my html and css down below as well as the link to my github repository.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

/*----------------Navbar----------------*/
.navbar {
  padding: .8rem;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}


.navbar-nav li {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mynav a {
  color: #474e5d;
}

.mynav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #DBA748;

}

.active a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #DBA748;

}

#nohover {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/*--------------Header----------------------*/
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.view {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

/*-----Column section------*/
.padding {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.padding-contact {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}



/*----Contact card--------*/

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 8px;
}

/*----Footer--------*/

.about-section {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #474e5d;
  color: white;
}


.title {
  color: grey;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}

/*-------footer icons---------*/
.footer-top {
  height: 100%;
  color: #191E20;
}

.social a {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.fa-instagram {
  color: #fff;

}

.fa-facebook {
  color: #fff;
}

.fa-twitter-square {
  color: #fff;
}

.fa-instagram:hover,
.fa-facebook:hover,
.fa-twitter-square:hover {
  color: #d5d5d5;
}

i.fab.fa-twitter-square,
i.fa-facebook,
i.fab.fa-instagram {
  background-color: #2c292f;
}

/*------Map-----*/
.embed-responsive-100x400px {
  padding-bottom: 400px;
}

/*----Send us a message card----*/
.head {
  background-color: #DBA748;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.btn1 {
  background: #DBA748;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 145px;
}

.btn1:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2E8097;
}

/*----Icon contact section----*/

.padding-icon {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.fa-phone {
  color: #fff;
}

.fa-envelope {
  color: #fff;
}

.fa-map-marker-alt {
  color: #fff;
}

i {
  background-color: #C3C4C6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.icon-about {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--Bootstrap css link-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--Google fonts link-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Font Awesome link-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b4c505ec35.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Link style.css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top mynav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="nohover"><img src="images/logga.png" alt="logo" width="90" height="120"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!--Full page image header-->
  <header>
    <div class="view" style="background-image: url('images/build.jpg'); height: 600px; ">
      <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
          <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <h1><span class="display-2 text-white">Construction Consultant</span></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!--Page content/main section-->

  <!-- welcome section -->
  <!--Column section-->
  <div class="container-fluid padding-contact">
    <div class="row welcome text-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="display-6">Build With Ease</h1>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--One column section-->
  <div class="container-fluid padding-contact">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">

        <p class="lead">Scared to take the first step, no idea how
          to begin a building project? Lucky you found us, we are
          exactly here for that reason! We help you take the first
          step towards your goal in the construction field leading you
          and many before into a great beginning. Feel free to learn
          more about how we work, read more <a href="about.html"> here!</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Three column section-->
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h2 class="heading text-center">Our Service</h2>
        <hr class="heading-divider heading-divider--black">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center padding">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <h3><i class="fas fa-comments icon-about"></i> Consulting</h3>
        <p>We consult new as well as old construction,
          to ensure that what you buy is of a good standard
          and stays stable in the future. If you are the one
          building we are then there to provide so that carpenters
          stay safe in their work environment and required papers
          are handed and provided to the right places. Curious to
          know more about how colnsulting works, check our about
          page and read more.</p>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <h3><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list icon-about"></i> Guidance</h3>
        <p>When you work with us we make sure to give you the best
          possible guidance in relation to construction. Meaning
          that when you feel that something seems a bit hard to
          understand, might be missing or are just wondering about
          what the best possible solution of a problem mig be?
          That's when we are here for you. In our about page you
          can find more information along what specific guidiance
          we provide, read more here.</p>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">

        <h3><i class="fas fa-hands-helping icon-about"></i> Final</h3>
        <p>Finishing a construction project is not just about hammering
          the last nail, in sweden it is more than that. That's why our
          consults are educated to make sure that every finishing touch
          of a construction are in place before giving you the final papper
          of the finished construction. Wanna know more about this process,
          read our about page. </p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <!--Two column section-->
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row padding">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2>Our Vision</h2>
        <p>Our vision is clear, straight forward and completely honest.
          We want to be the main company people turn to when wanting to
          build things as houses, apartments, magazines or why not a stable
          and so on. When it comes to us we imagine construction in the
          building field being a adventure, it requires a lot and we know
          many people starting projects like this have grown a lot thanks to
          such a journey. They can be challenging but we imagine that having
          us by your side will only provide with a fine result that lead to good
          environment, futuristic thinking, more workspaces, homes and happy faces. </p>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="images/begin.jpg" alt="Pictur of mug" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <!--Contact card-->

  <br>
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; ">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/John.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">John Doe</p>
            <p class="card-text"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
              <a href="tel:+555-555-555"> +555-555-555</a></p>
            <p class="card-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i><a href="john.doe@gmail.com">
                john.doe@gmail.com</a></p>
            <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-primary">Send a Message</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--End of page content-->

  <!-- footer -->
  <!--Short description of company-->
  <footer style="background-color: #2c292f">
    <div class="container-fluid padding">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm text-white text-center text-md-center">
          <br>
          <span class=" font-weight-bold ">About the Company</span>
          <p class="text-warning my-2">We offer consulting for you who are ready to start
            a building project and want professional guidiance trough your journey in the building field.
          </p>
        </div>

        <!--Social links & Icons-->
        <div class="col-sm text-white text-center text-md-center">
          <br>
          <span class="font-weight-bold">Connect</span>
          <br>
          <div class="social padding">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="https://sv-se.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Extra menu for site-->
        <div class="col-sm text-center text-md-center">
          <div class="py-0">
            <h3 class="my-4 text-white">About<span class="mx-2 font-italic text-warning ">CC</span></h3>

            <p class="footer-links font-weight-bold">
              <a class="text-white" href="index.html"> Home</a>
              |
              <a class="text-white" href="about.html"> About</a>
              |
              <a class="text-white" href="contact.html"> Contact</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- end of footer -->


  <!--Javascript-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <!--End of javascript-->

</body>

</html>
```

[Here is my repository](https://github.com/TjoAlex/constructionconsultant)

Thank you for taking your time helping a newbie as me :)

Comment: right side space on a mobile device or desktop?

Comment: can you mabye post some screenshots of what you describe as a issue here? so we can have a better idea about it

Comment: This is the link https://tjoalex.github.io/constructionconsultant/

Comment: Try lowering or removing the `font-size` in your `display-2` class. this fixed the bug for me

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I tried that before posting this question but because I didn't have a breakpoint as Ruchit Micro mentioned that still didn't work. Yet after fixing a breakpoint by following boostrap library the issue was solved, glad you gave me the sugestion anyways!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not have a breakpoint to reset the size of your h1 tag.
2. You have a card for John Doe at the bottom of the page where you have given an inline width of 18rem.

Comment: OMG!!! So simple yet so hard for me to realise, thank you so so much for your response @Ruchit Micro!

Comment: please mark it as an answer if it solved your problem, it will help others who got stuck as well

Comment: A sure I fixed that now, once again thank you!